# Idris: Proving some contradiction cases

Tags: proof, idris

I am new to Idris and Proofs in general but I am progressing through Software Foundations ported to Idris.  I am working on an exercise

```
namespace Booleans

  data Bool = True | False

  andb : Booleans.Bool -> Booleans.Bool  -> Booleans.Bool
  andb True b = b
  andb False _ = False

  orb : Booleans.Bool -> Booleans.Bool -> Booleans.Bool
  orb True _ = True
  orb False b = b

  (&&) : Booleans.Bool -> Booleans.Bool  -> Booleans.Bool
  (&&) = andb

  (||) : Booleans.Bool -> Booleans.Bool  -> Booleans.Bool
  (||) = orb

  andb_eq_orb : (b, c : Booleans.Bool) -> (b && c = b || c) -> b = c
```

there are obviously four cases and two hold for reflexivity.

```
  andb_eq_orb True True _ = Refl
  andb_eq_orb True False prf = ?rhs1
  andb_eq_orb False True prf = ?rhs2
  andb_eq_orb False False _ = Refl
```

Checking the holes reveals

```
Main.Booleans.rhs1
    prf : True && False = True || False
---------------------------------
Main.Booleans.rhs1 : True = False

Main.Booleans.rhs2
    prf : False && True = False || True
---------------------------------
Main.Booleans.rhs2 : False = True
```

I don't understand that while the assertions are obviuosly illogical that is what I need to prove for those two steps.  I don't see any  rewrite steps I could make.  More but abstractly I dont understand the approach or pattern to solve this either logically or explicitly in the langauge (Idris).

---

I am able to get both of the approaches to work by implementing the Uninhabbited interface for the type signature as such:

```
Uninhabited (Booleans.True && Booleans.False = Booleans.True || Booleans.False) where
    uninhabited Refl impossible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how did you define `&&` and `||` and why they don't reduce for you, so let me show how this would work for stdlib `Bool`:

If you write the following:

```
andb_eq_orb : (b, c : Bool) -> (b && c = b || c) -> b = c
andb_eq_orb True  True  _   = Refl
andb_eq_orb True  False prf = ?rhs1
andb_eq_orb False True  prf = ?rhs2
andb_eq_orb False False _   = Refl
```

then

```
> :t rhs1
prf : False = True
--------------------------------------
rhs1 : True = False
Holes: Booleans.rhs2, Booleans.rhs1

 > :t rhs2
prf : False = True
--------------------------------------
rhs2 : False = True
```

One way you could fill this would be simply by passing through these reduced proofs, swapping the sides where necessary:

```
andb_eq_orb : (b, c : Bool) -> (b && c = b || c) -> b = c
andb_eq_orb True  True  _   = Refl
andb_eq_orb True  False prf = sym prf
andb_eq_orb False True  prf = prf
andb_eq_orb False False _   = Refl
```

Another, proper way to do this would be to use [the Uninhabited interface](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/Prelude/Uninhabited.idr), which gives you a proof of `Void` given a contradictory premise. You can then use a `void : Void -> a` function (aka [the principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)), or a convenient synonym `absurd = void . uninhabited`:

```
andb_eq_orb : (b, c : Bool) -> (b && c = b || c) -> b = c
andb_eq_orb True  True  _   = Refl
andb_eq_orb True  False prf = absurd prf
andb_eq_orb False True  prf = absurd prf
andb_eq_orb False False _   = Refl
```

Comment: Added implementatiosns of `&&` and `||`.  There also seems to be some difference between my version of Bool and the version provided by prelude as evidenced by me switching the type out and viewing the holes.  Your first implementation works for me.  However when I try the second one I encouter `"Can't find implementation for Uninhabited"`.

Comment: Yes, because `Uninhabited` is an interface, i.e. a vehicle for ad-hoc polymorphism, you have to implement it manually for the types you introduce. It's not that hard in this case: `Uninhabited (False = True) where
      uninhabited Refl impossible`, `Uninhabited (True = False) where
  uninhabited Refl impossible` (the formatting is off but I hope you get the idea)